# how to make a bottom nav bar like this in flutter without using any package?

Tags: flutter

how to make a custom bottom nav bar like this in the link below with flutter ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBx2X.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this package [convex_bottom_bar: ^3.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar)

This package has lots of different types of bottom bar designs.